# Reduction between parametrized problems

Tags: complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity

Can we construct reduction from $k$-sum to $l$-clique or vice versa where $k$ and $l$ are some fixed integers?

That is given two parametrized problems whose unparametrized version is $NP$-complete when can we construct reductions between them?

In general NP complete problems the reductions are polynomial time.

What is the corresponding analogue in parametrized problems?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions, I will answer the second. Parameterized reduction from problem $P$ to $Q$ is a function $\phi$ with the following properties :

- $\phi(x)$ can be computed in time  $f (k)·|x|^{O(1)}$, where $k$ is the parameter of $x$,
- $\phi(x)$ is a yes-instance of $Q$ if and only if $x$ is a yes-instance of $P$.
- If $k$ is the parameter of $x$ and $k′$ is the parameter of $\phi(x)$, then $k′ ≤ g(k)$ for some function $g$.

> Note that $f(k)$ need not to be a polynomial function in $k$, it could be like $2^k$ or $c^k$, where $c$ is constant.

Example: INDEPENDENT-SET instance $(G,K)$ into CLIQUE instance $(G',K)$ is a parameterized reduction. You can verify all three conditions mentioned above.

**Reference :** http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/marx-warsaw-fpt3